# El TNS de Oracle funciona inestablemente

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, sqlplus, toad

tengo una base de datos Oracle la cual, desde hace unos dias cuando me toco apagar el servidor por cuestiones de mantenimiento de la red electrica, empezo a andar de forma extraña.

Vinculada a esa bd tengo una app web la cual por momentos muetra un error de "ORA-12541: No hay ningun listener", por momentos se queda cargando como intentando conectarse pero por momentos funciona perfectamente, a su vez cuando a la hora de entrar al Toad o al SQLPLUS me tira los mismos errores de TNS aun cuando la aplicacion web funciona correctamente:
[image: TOAD con error ORA-12541]

[image: SQLPLUS con error de TNS]

Hay momentos en los que al ingresar a la base de datos mediante Toad o SQLPLUS el proceso se cuelga (No Responde) por lo que tengo que forzar el cierre o si lo dejo procesando al rato largo u horas ingresa y de todas formas la aplicacion web se comporta de la misma forma (por momentos anda, por momentos arroja error de que no hay ningun listener o se queda cargando).

Ya probe: reiniciando servicios desde el Services.msc y *lsnrctl stop* y *lsnrctl start*, reiniciando procesos desde Administrador de Tareas, reiniciando el servidor, cambiando algunas configuraciones del *listener.ora* y *tnsnames.ora* la cual no deberia ser problema porque hasta la semana pasada funcionaba correctamente

Adjunto fotos
[image: lsnrctl status]

Ejecutando un *tnsping*

[image: tnsping ServidorHP]

Tambien adjunto la configuracion de *listener.ora* y *tnsnames.ora*

LISTENER.ORA

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\Oracle\Administrador\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\Oracle\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ServidorHP)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\Oracle\Administrador
```

TNSNAMES.ORA

```
    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\Oracle\Administrador\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ServidorHP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Tambien comento que el servicio esta corriendo en el puerto 1521 como figura en *netstat -ab*

Comment: Y la pregunta es?

Comment: Sale algo relacionado en el visor de eventos de windows? A la hora que te sale que no hay listener, hay algún evento?

Comment: @Arriel la pregunta creo que se entiende es: que puede estar sucediendo? o como soluciono esta situacion?

Comment: @Alfabravo no se registran eventos de error o que llamen la atencion

Comment: Si no ves reinicios, procesos del sistema o eventos inusuales, te toca hacer seguimiento y revisar si otros servicios en ese servidor están disponibles al momento del fallo, ver si hay algún lío en la red, en un equipo intermedio (switch o router, equipo de seguridad, etc),...

Comment: @Alfabravo muchas gracias, lo tendre en cuenta! saludos